# Flask и Jinja2. Наличие значения в списке словарей

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Как проверить имеется ли внутри списка словарей ключ с определенным значением:

Как пример: `[{'a':0,'b':1,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}]`

И нужно внутри jinja2 проверить есть ли ключ "b" со значением "2"

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, что в вашей функции вы передаёте этот список через переменную `context` :

```
context = [{'a':0,'b':1,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}]
return render_template('temp.html', context=context)
```

Тогда в шаблоне `temp.html` это будет выглядеть так:

```
{% for dct in context %}
    {% if 'b' in dct.keys() %}
        {% if dct.b == 2 %}
            <p>Найден словарь с "b" = {{ dct.b }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Сначала циклом проходим по каждому словарю. Проверяем, есть ли в словаре `dct` ключ `b`. Если такой ключ есть, то проверяем, равен ли этот ключ `b` значению `2`. Если нашли совпадение, выводим тег.

=========================================================

Дополнение в соответствии с комментариями. Сразу в функции представления попробовать найти нужные ключ-значение и передать True/False в шаблон.

```
s = [{'a':0,'b':1,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}]

for dct in s:
    if ('b', 2) in dct.items():
        context = True
        break
    else:
        context = False

return render_template('temp.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Но в этом случае, при наличии нескольких ключей с удовлетворяющими условия значениями, он повторно напишет что найден словарь

Comment: Если у вас в списке есть несколько словарей с ключом-значением 'b':2 [{'a':0,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}], то цикл найдёт их все. Разве что-то не так?

Comment: В том то и проблема что требуется только наличие

Comment: Мне сложно понять, чего вы хотите. Мой код сейчас делает ровно то, что вы задали в вопросе, т.е. находит все словари, в которых содержится 'b':2. В вашем примере из 3-х словарей будет найден средний ({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}), т.к. в нём содержится 'b':2, а в 2-х других не содержится.

Comment: Есть варианты где встречается ключ со значением несколько раз за список и требуется сообщить только об одном

Comment: А как читатель должен был эту инфу узнать из вашего вопроса? Тут не битва экстрасенсов. Ну и допустим есть список[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}], в котором в 3-х словарях содержится 'b':2. Какой из словарей вам нужно получить? Первый попавшийся? Последний? Рандомный?

Comment: Просто наличие в любом из них, если хотя бы в одном из них имеется = True

Comment: Тогда лучше обрабатывать это всё дело внутри функции и в шаблон передавать результат. Дополнил вопрос примером.